# Address of interrupt handler. How can i obtain it?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following code that reads a number from the keyboard:

```
 number dw ?

    ok db 0
    stop db "that's not a number$"
again:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
jmp compare

compare:
cmp al, 0x30
jg greater
mov ok,0
lesser:
mov ok, 1
jmp next
greater:
cmp al, 0x39
jl lesser
mov ok, 0

next:
cmp ok, 1
je go
cmp ok, 0
je notdigit

notdigit:
lea dx, stop
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp again

go:
sub al, '0'
add bh, al
jmp go4

go2:
sub al, '0'
add bl, al
shl bl,4
jmp go3



go4:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
jmp go2
jmp again

go3:
mov ah, 1
int 21h
sub al, '0'
add bl,al
mov number, bx
jmp go_on

go_on:
```

So now i have a number let's say between 0 and 255. This is my interrupt number and now i have to multiply it by 4 to get the address of the handler. Will it work just like that? Is it enough to multiply my number by 4 to get the start address of the handler? For eg: if i read let's say 21 the address would be 84, right? Also is there any problem if my number is like 0021H or 0xxxH? The zeros are ignored, right? So it would just be 21H, XXXh?

I need to print the address of the handler on the screen. How do i do that after the multiplication?

Comment: Multiplying by 4 gives you the address of the handler, not the handler itself. You probably want to read the pointer from memory and print that. Otherwise your code would just be a multiplication-by-4 calculator. To print it, you need to convert it back to text. PS: your text to number conversion is broken.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? In the end i have 3 digits in my variable "number". Something like 0234h. Yes, maybe it's not the best algorithm to do that. Or do you mean that it is not working the way i want? Could you be more specific, please? I'm just getting started with ASM.

Comment: You don't zero `bx` just add to it so no telling what the result will be. Even if it is correct, it's going to be BCD which is difficult to use in calculations. Also, you only check if the first character is a digit and blindly process the rest. That also means the user must enter e.g. `007` can't do `7`.